# List without indenting the first line

Tags: alignment

I am listing a bunch of text as follows:

```
\subsection*{List of SRR IDs of samples we throw out}
SRR1578746

SRR1578747

SRR6761043

SRR6761044

SRR6761045
```

This renders as follows:

[image]

As you can see, all lines except the first indent. I want to remove the indent. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are several different options that all result in uniformly indented lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\subsection*{List of SRR IDs of samples we throw out}

{
\makeatletter\@afterindenttrue\makeatother
SRR1578746

SRR1578747

SRR6761043

SRR6761044

SRR6761045
}

\subsection*{List of SRR IDs of samples we throw out}

{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
SRR1578746

SRR1578747

SRR6761043

SRR6761044

SRR6761045
}

\subsection*{List of SRR IDs of samples we throw out}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
SRR1578746 \\
SRR1578747 \\
SRR6761043 \\
SRR6761044 \\
SRR6761045 \\
\end{tabular}

\subsection*{List of SRR IDs of samples we throw out}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
SRR1578746 

SRR1578747 

SRR6761043 

SRR6761044 

SRR6761045 

\end{minipage}

\subsection*{List of SRR IDs of samples we throw out}

\begin{itemize}
\item SRR1578746 
\item SRR1578747 
\item SRR6761043 
\item SRR6761044 
\item SRR6761045 
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

[image]